# Creating mp3 from audio

Tags: audio, mp3

I've already posted this question on "Music Fans" SE, but getting no answers from there - I hope that someone here might have some ideas.

I have some CDs with copy protection that I would like to rip to MP3s.

I have Ableton Live Lite 10 - so used it to record the Audio from the tracks - then thought I could Export the audio as MP3 from Ableton.

It sort-of worked - but created a file with a ".mp3.als" extension which tries to open in Ableton.

So, I changed the extension to ".mp3" and tried to open it in Windows Media Player, but got "Invalid File" or similar.

It's interesting though, because the file is the right size for an mp3, and when I tried it with Wav and Flac files, they were also the kind of size you would expect them to be - but with the same result.

Any idea how I can make an mp3 that is playable normally, either using Ableton or something else?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the Ableton Live user manual would be a good start in understanding how to operate their software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: @Tetsujin I read the Ableton manual in this area and produced what Ableton think is an mp3 - but unfortunately it is not, it is an mp3.als, which, I hope you agree, is not the same thing. I can find no reference anywhere why Ableton think it's the same thing, so please can you point me to where I can find this obvious information.

Comment: @Tetsujin Why is it a Basic Customer Support question please?

Comment: Have you tried CDEX to rip the music to wave or mp3>>>>https://cdex.mu/

Comment: There are many Apps that can open and export or save as including Audacity

Comment: From the manual… ".als = ableton live set or template set (contains the layout of a set, such as tracks, devices, Clips etc)." ..so, no, you didn't save a midi file. Understanding how to use your software is not a topic for Super User, it's one for the manufacturer of the software.

Comment: @Tetsujin Exactly my problem. ".als" is an "Ableton Live Set" - i.e. the entire composition  that I create using Ableton. So you would assume that, having created a composition and are happy with your finished work, you can save it to any "music" format that somebody might want to play in the outside world. Someone who doesn't have Ableton. So you choose "Export to mp3". Or Flac, or wav. What you get is an "mp3.als" which can only open in Ableton.

Comment: I don't use Ableton personally, but I've yet to find anyone who does who can't send me an mp3 of their finished work. It is really not the job of this site to teach you how to use your software, sorry.

Comment: Please can everyone vote to close this question as I can't close it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Media Player, you can follow this tutorial to rip music into mp3 format.

https://ccm.net/faq/34362-windows-media-player-allow-the-import-of-copy-protected-audio-files

### Allow the Import of Copy Protected Audio Files in Windows Media Player

Are you finding that Windows Media Player is unable to rip tracks from audio CDs? This article will show you how to enable the import of protected audio files.

#### How to Import Copy Protected Audio Files

- Click on the Tools menu > Options > Rip Music.
- In the "Rip settings" section, check "Copy protect music"
- Click on OK to validate.

[image: Windows Media Player]

Comment: Thanks for the constructive suggestion. To summarise for future-proof-ness, it seems to suggest that I can rip the CDs as long as I'm happy for WMP to copy-protect them usin RIP Options/Enable Copy Protect. Assuming this works, I don't want them copy-protected anyway, because the whole point of the exercise is to get the mp3s onto my phone and other devices.